# How to calculate the force acting on a magnet due to a solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

Can I assume both magnet and solenoid as magnetic dipole and use Coulombs law to find the force acting the magnet?

Comment: Define these things: Current through the solenoid, number of windings, material on which the solenoid is wound, shape of the solenoid, magnet material, magnet shape, magnet magnetization direction and intensity, relative position of the solenoid and the magnet.

Comment: I wonder if you could tackle this by writing down the energy from the two when separated by a distance $d$ and taking $\partial E/ \partial d$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the force acting on a dipole $\vec{m}$ in a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ (like the field of a solenoid) is $$\vec{F} = \nabla(\vec{m} \cdot \vec{B})$$

How would you use Columb's law? That's for charges.

Answer (score 0):

You must obtain the magnetic field due to the solenoid according to the approximate calculations according to its dimensions. If the magnet is small you can easily found the torque, and also the force when it is in a region of non uniformity.

Comment: Please elaborate.  Small relative to what? "Find" a magnetic field?